# localized file names display incorrectly after uploading with openFileChooser() in android webView

Tags: android, webview

Android webView can upload files with a file picker by using the hidden method openFileChooser(). This can work well with file with English names. But when uploading files with localized names, like "你好.txt", the file name displays incorrectly in a un-decoded Uri style("%E4%BD%A0%E5%BD.txt"). As I can only pass a Uri, there's no way I can find to pass a Uri decoded file name. How can I resolve this issue?

Code example:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        Uri result = intent.getData();
        mUpload.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUpload = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide and example (or 2) of what you see now and what you would like to see? The Uri class has toString() and parse(String) - so you could String aTempUri = result.toString() format aTempUri as you want and then parse(aTempUri). I'm not sure this is what you want as parse() may just reformat.

Comment: For example, I'm opening a page which has a file picker and let me choose file. The page can be as simple as below:   
`<html>  <body>
<input type="file"/>
</body>
</html>`  
When I click and choose a local file, it will display the file name on the page. If I chose a file named "你好.txt", on webview it shows "%E4%BD%A0%E5%BD.txt". I'd like to see "你好.txt". I'v tried re-formating the Uri, it results the same. Because the new Uri will encode the localized strings to Uri format too, and is the same as old one.